# symfony doctrine admin generator class not found

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4, admin-generator

I get the following error in my doctrine generated module that I generated using

```
symfony doctrine:generate-module --generate-in-cache frontend module_name ModelName
```

I have tried clearing the cache.

```
Fatal error: Class '{Module Name}GeneratorConfiguration' not found
```

I changed the theme to use jroller which is installed and working on other generated modules and they work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I had to create classes in lib for ModuleNameGeneratorConfiguration and ModuleNameGeneratorHelper and extend from the base classes